# How to integrate OpenCV in a C++ project build by gradle

Tags: c++, opencv, gradle

I set up a `hello world` project [here](https://bitbucket.org/BenNG/hello-cpp/src/11e229362b4788afb24d99f16f40a8c93c496770?at=master) which is basically a copy/paste of the samples from the gradle project [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/native-binaries/cpp).

My next step is a `hello world` but for the OpenCV framework. It's going to read a picture in memory and display it. To be precise, the `main.cpp` will we more like that

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );
    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I include the OpenCV header but I'm struggling adding the lib itself via gradle. I probably have to use the [prebuilt](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/tree/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/native-binaries/prebuilt) way but I fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure headers and prebuilt library linkings:

I usually do in android, but I cannot assure that it works, because I do not know what is your gradle plugin. 
But you can use as a clue, depending on your gradle version the syntax can change.

Firstly define your opencv directory:

```
opencv.dir="the site where opencv headers are"
```

After define your opencv libs, define your headers.srcDir

```
repositories {
  libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
    opencv_core {
    headers.srcDir "your opencv.dir"
      binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) { binary ->
        // This closure will be executed once for every buildType/platform combination
        def variantDir = binary.targetPlatform.architecture.name == 'i386' ? 'Win32' : 'x64'
        staticLibraryFile = "path/to/library/${variantDir}/opencv_core.so"
      }
    }
    opencv_another_lib {
    headers.srcDir "your opencv.dir"
      binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) { binary ->
        // This closure will be executed once for every buildType/platform combination
        def variantDir = binary.targetPlatform.architecture.name == 'i386' ? 'Win32' : 'x64'
        staticLibraryFile = "path/to/library/${variantDir}/opencv_another_lib.so"
      }
    }
  }
```

probably, for example opencv_core will have more 3rparty dependencies, try adding in the same way.

I hope this helps.

Cheers.

Unai.